# EOF-Exception when deserializing a byte[] in JAVA

Tags: java, serialization, eof

I am currently trying to programm an encrypted chat working in my local network. This is the code where I try to deserialize the data that I received.

```
if (dp.getData() != null) {
            try {
                empfangen = (ArrayList<byte[]>) Serial.toObject(dp.getData());
            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Verbindung.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
```

And this is the method that I use to deserialize this data into an Object.

```
 public static Object toObject(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    ObjectInput in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
    Object o = in.readObject();
    in.close();
    bis.close();
    return o;
}
```

However I get an EOF-Exception with this code and I do not know how to fix it. Can anyone help?
This is the output:

```
java.io.EOFException  at
java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2754)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1688)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1345)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
  at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:791)   at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
  at
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1900)
  at
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
  at cryptchat.Serial.toObject(Serial.java:50)    at
cryptchat.Verbindung$1.run(Verbindung.java:66)
```

Comment: How did you write this object? And how did you read the data in `getData()`?

Comment: `public static byte[] toByteArray(Object objekt) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        out.writeObject(objekt);
        byte[] temp = bos.toByteArray();
        out.close();
        bos.close();
        return temp;
   }`

Comment: We read the data through the DatagramPacket it is a ready method calle `.getdata(); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to dump the bytes on the sending side, dump the bytes on the receiving side, compare, and then diagnose. Apparently, all the bytes aren't getting across the wire (datagrams do have size limits) or they are corrupted.

Comment: Do u know the max size?

Comment: Depends on the configuration of all of the routers in the network.

Comment: Ok... but how can I split them?

Comment: Why are you using datagrams at all? They are very tricky. Why not make connections? And I may not be right about the size limit, you need to dump the data and see. You may have some other data corruption issue.